# How to get a review page link or review files for a certain drug using API on FDA?

Tags: openfda

I wanna get the review link for a certain drug links via API, e.g, for the drug "AUBAGIO", it's

"http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Set_Current_Drug&ApplNo=202992&DrugName=AUBAGIO&ActiveIngred=TERIFLUNOMIDE&SponsorApplicant=SANOFI%20AVENTIS%20US&ProductMktStatus=1&goto=Search.Label_ApprovalHistory"

And that can be access by search "Abagio", then within the drug page, click on the "Approval History, Letters, Reviews, and Related Documents".

That link refers to the review link I need.
So is there any possible way to obtain that using API or programmatically?
If there is no way to do that, how I can obtain the review pdf files or file link for each certain drugs? 
Coz I'm going to fetch the review pdf files for each drugs approved in a certain year. I am thinking that first I can locate a unique link for each drug, and then to get the review files, which are just on the page, is not hard. Or if there is a way that can directly locate the review files would be better.

Thank you!